# Guake terminal appearance like a normal terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, guake

I love how the normal terminal looks on Ubuntu.

I recently installed Guake and the Guake terminal is pretty simple (ugly): white on black with a simple font. Furthermore it's inconsistent with other terminal windows.

Is there a way to have Guake use the same appearance/theme than the normal terminals?

---

**Update:**

Ubuntu terminal:

[image: terminal]

Guake terminal:

[image: guake terminal]

As you can see, the font and the background color is not the same. (I also just noticed that the normal terminal is not using zsh, even though I `chsh` earlier before opening the terminal)

Comment: Which is your "normal" terminal?

Comment: There are quite a few options in `guake` preferences (right click within `quake` or use `guake -p`. There are very similar options to the 'normal' Ubuntu default terminal (`gnome-terminal`).

Comment: @desgua I just did a clean install of Ubuntu so the "default" one? (gnome terminal maybe?)

Comment: @Mik I already tried all options but I get nothing close. I'll try to add some screens to the question.

Comment: @Matthieu yes, it is gnome-terminal ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you right click on the Guake icon in the top right hand corner, you get 3 options:

`Preferences`
`About`
`Quit`

By going to Preferences and going to `Appearance`, you should be able to edit your Guake terminal to look the same as your other terminal windows.

[image: Guake properties]

[image: Guake after editing properties]

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Just noticed the comments after the question, (Oops!) Will leave the answer as it may help other Guake users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as you can see in the screens I added to the question, this doesn't do it.

Comment: I just checked your edit - Have you set Transparency to as far left as you can then change the background colour to a custom  background colour (purplish)? I will throw in an edit with a new picture showing how mine looks similar to yours. If there's something else missing, could you let me know? :) If you can't set yours like that, try rebooting Guake, as it didn't automatically work for me either.

Comment: I was hoping for a more automated solution but I just figured thanks to your answer that I can configure the colors using a pipette. So I was able to select exactly the same colors. I also had to configure the same font and font size, but now it's all good!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. I do agree there should be an automated solution. I'll see if there is one and edit my answer if so. If not, it may be good for people to put that idea forward to the Guake devs, for it to mimic the default terminal.